# Dispatch actions from a custom hook using useQuery

Tags: react-hooks, react-redux, react-query

I'm trying to write a custom hook that uses `useQuery` from `react-query`. The custom hook takes in the `id` of an employee and fetches some data and returns it to the consuming component. I want to be able to `dispatch` a redux action to show a loading indicator or show an error message if it fails. Here is my custom hook.

```js
export default function useEmployee(id) {
  const initial = {
    name: '',
    address: '',
  }

  const query = useQuery(['fetchEmployee', id], () => getEmployee(id), {
    initialData: initial,
    onSettled: () => dispatch(clearWaiting()),
    onError: (err) => dispatch(showError(err)),
  })
  if (query.isFetching || query.isLoading) {
    dispatch(setWaiting())
  }
  return query.data
}
```

When I refresh the page, I get this error in the browser's console and I'm not sure how to fix this error?

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`WaitIndicator`) while rendering a different component (`About`). 
To locate the bad setState() call inside `About`, follow the stack trace as described in
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely with dispatching the `setWaiting` action *outside* any component lifecycle, i.e. `useEffect`. Move the dispatch logic into a `useEffect` hook with appropriate dependency.

Example:

```
export default function useEmployee(id) {
  const initial = {
    name: '',
    address: '',
  };

  const { data, isFetching, isLoading } = useQuery(['fetchEmployee', id], () => getEmployee(id), {
    initialData: initial,
    onSettled: () => dispatch(clearWaiting()),
    onError: (err) => dispatch(showError(err)),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFetching || isLoading) {
      dispatch(setWaiting());
    }
  }, [isFetching, isLoading]);
  
  return data;
}
```

Comment: while this answer is correct in answering the question, the question itself is a bit weird. Why would you want to do that? It does seem like an anti-pattern to me to sync loading states from react-query to redux to show loading spinners...

Comment: @TkDodo It doesn't seem that odd to me at all to sync any loading state into app state if there're possibly other components that necessarily need to know the loading state of fetched data. If OP was using `redux-toolkit/query` with an API slice instead of `react-query`, would storing/tracking the loading status be anti-pattern in your opinion then? It's effectively the same thing but the coupling of query statuses and app state is already handled.

Comment: I just meant that react-query already make the loading state of queries globally available, so if other components need it, they can access it. `useIsFetching` would be one way for example.

Comment: @TkDodo Ah, I see. Admittedly I'm not very familiar with `react-query` specifics.